# Get the Startup List via WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

How do I gat the the full .exe path

Let us assume with the following string strt["Command"].ToString(); 
I get this output

> C:\Program Files\Analog
>   Devices\SoundMAX\soundmax.exe /tray

but how to I get

> C:\Program Files\Analog
>   Devices\SoundMAX\soundmax.exe

```
ManagementClass mangnmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_StartupCommand");
ManagementObjectCollection mcol = mangnmt.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject strt in mcol)
{
    string[] lv = new String[4];
    lv[0] = strt["Caption"].ToString();
    lv[1] = strt["Location"].ToString();
    lv[2] = strt["Command"].ToString();
    lv[3] = strt["Description"].ToString();
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(lv, 0));
}
```

Comment: Unclear question. Please explain more detail what exactly do you need.

Comment: Isn't it in "Location" i.e. lv[1]?

Comment: Please don't put "C#" in the title - you've already got it in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
   FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Analog Devices\SoundMAX\soundmax.exe /tray");
   Console.WriteLine(fi.DirectoryName);
```

Comment: Thank you for the input but this no working. Im dealing with always various locations